# Can't see runtime E_ERROR errors in WAMP server PHP program?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, error-logging

Something in my PHP script is causing a fatal error, but I ca't seem to log or display it. My `php.ini` file has

> error_reporting = E_ALL

and is logging to a file. I can see `E_USER_ERROR` errors I trigger in the log file and on my screen, but the `E_ERROR` in my program just gives me a white screen and no log output. What else do I need to do?

I'm running on WAMPServer 2.2, on a Windows 7 box

Comment: Nothing shows up in the log? Maybe not a PHP error or PHP just crashes so it can't write the log any longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an impossible question to answer as asked, and I need to share why- the offending code that was causing this error was buried in a proprietary framework I'm working against, that had this line:

> @include_once( $file ) ;

What's the `@` symbol? I didn't know- now I do: It silences all errors. Stupid and evil and ruined my day.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

you can put this in your main .php script (replace E_ALL with the desired debug level)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```